# Working with subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mobile

I have few questions regarding subdomains in my mind. I know how to get a subdomain and redirect to it using `.htaccess` or placing js file in our directory.

My questions are:

1. Suppose I have a website `www.mysite.com` and I want to redirect
   mobile users to `m.mysite.com`. Can I place `js` file with
   redirecting code anywhere in the directory or should it be in
   specific path?
2. I want different functioning and styling for mobile users for which
   I have to write a separate code.  Where will I place this mobile
   friendly code and link it to redirecting code? I don't want to use
   any app or web service for this.

Comment: You may want to find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: What is **itaccess** ?

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose I have a website www.mysite.com and I want to redirect mobile users to m.mysite.com.

This could save your day: [What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery)

> Can I place js file with redirecting code anywhere in the directory or should it be in specific path?

It doesn't depend where you put the `.js` file, you have to include it in the respective file.

```
<script src="path/to/file.js"></script>
```